# Extracting Google Map routes as shape

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps, google-maps-static-api

We have very simple example of transition route in Web Google Map. Consider [following example link](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/40.9003893,-74.1943228/2-22+Taft+Ave,+Woodland+Park,+NJ+07424,+USA/40.898207,-74.1952972/40.8987253,-74.1968851/40.9008121,-74.196019/@40.8994414,-74.1947649,16.25z/data=!4m12!4m11!1m0!1m5!1m1!1s0x89c2fe0b277654c5:0xe2ef2499f02796f6!2m2!1d-74.1953885!2d40.900987!1m0!1m0!1m0!3e2). Or image, below.

[image: Or this Image].

My question is, how to get **this shape of the route** with some Map API(maybe not Google)? So I'm trying to make script, where I can insert a lot of points of the destination, and the output should be **the shape of the transition routes**. Even I can make shape with OpenCV, all  what I need, it's just thumbnail of such route.

---

- What I have tried so far? It's using Google Map Static API to create thumbnail. However, from the documentation, it's not possible to create such routes representation. By using `path` field in Static API with same destination points (provided in link above), we would have just connection lines. Example below and [link to the Map Request](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=650x300&center=40.8994414,-74.1947649&zoom=16&path=color:0x0000ff%7Cweight:5%7C40.9003893,-74.1943228%7C2-22%20Taft%20Ave,%20Woodland%20Park,%20NJ%2007424,%20USA%7C40.898207,-74.1952972%7C40.8987253,-74.1968851%7C40.9008121,-74.196019&key=AIzaSyBp3qT02RHZ-nFuaB0QPqinrLpdz0kCZGU).

[image]

- What about if you put your points in the appropriate order? Let me explain, why order won't help in this case. Check the another [example here](https://goo.gl/maps/DR2UufEDKrv). Or first image below. Now, lets take those points to the Static Map API. And you will have second image below. Or [this link to API Request](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=650x300&center=40.8994414,-74.1947649&zoom=16&path=color:0x0000ff%7Cweight:5%7C40.8993846,-74.19484%7C48-2%20Garden%20Ave,%20Woodland%20Park,%20NJ%2007424,%20USA%7C40.8994819,-74.1983376&key=AIzaSyBp3qT02RHZ-nFuaB0QPqinrLpdz0kCZGU). **So it's not about order**, but behavior (which is obviously, is very different applications).

[image: Another Example]

[image]

Comment: What about if you put your points in the appropriate order?

Comment: @MrUpsidown It's not about order, but their behavior. Order is the same on both pictures, but for the first one, Google Maps choosing  transition routes. Where the second, just absolute path between them. Another thing, it's in very complicated shapes, it won't be possible to track order.

Comment: In first example, it goes from (1) 18 Taft av. to (2) 2-22 Taft av. then (3) 59 Woodrow av. which means the path goes back on its own track. In the static maps example, you are just using points 1 then 2 then 3 (it's just a path, not a Directions request!). So if you would need the same, you would need points 1, then 2, then 1, then 3, etc. or, you need to reorder the points (2, 1, 3, 4, 5).

Comment: @MrUpsidown Check my new Image examples above. You don't need to much, to understand, why it doesn't work. Thanks.

Comment: Obviously, as I said above... You are requesting **Directions** from Google Maps website and you are requesting just a **path** to be drawn on Maps Static API. These are 2 very different things.

Comment: @MrUpsidown Then why you asked about `appropriate order`?

Comment: Because in the first example you gave, if they were in what I'd consider the appropriate order, you would have the same path drawn (more or less...) as your path is quite straightforward. But let's forget about that. To answer your question, you should request the Directions with the Maps API (Javascript or Directions web service) then extract its path, then request that path to be drawn on Maps Static.

Comment: A few things you might want to note: Directions API limits you in the number of waypoints you can use in your requests. Not sure if that also applies to the number of points you can add to a path on Maps Static API. That said, and instead of using the path parameter, you can use an **encoded Polyline**, which you will also get via a Directions request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is now a bit too broad and so will be my answer, but I'll summarize here what you *could* do.

1. Request your Directions with the [JS API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/directions) or the [Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/start).
2. Use [Waypoints](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#Waypoints) in your request to specify each point. **Warning**: limitations apply (23 waypoints + origin & destination).
3. In your Directions response, you can use either the `overview_path` or the `overview_polyline` to draw that same route on the Maps Static API. Note that both are **simplified** paths (smoothed) that are less precise than the exact Polyline you get from the API. Maybe that is enough for your use case. Read more [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/directions#DirectionsRoute).
4. Alternatively, if you need the exact Polyline coordinates, you will have to extract it from each [DirectionsStep](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/directions#DirectionsStep) returned by the API.
5. Once you have your path points (or encoded Polyline), you can request your [Maps Static API path](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/dev-guide#Paths) (also see about encoded Polylines at the bottom of that page).

Hope this helps.